# Why can't I interact with my components within my modal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, modal-dialog, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a modal and for some reason I cannot interact with any components like buttons or inputs within my modal.

I am building a React Portal, so that my modal and page are separate from each other and that the modal is not "running" in the background when it is not in use

```
import {useState, useLayoutEffect} from "react"
import { createPortal } from "react-dom"

const createWrapperAndAppendToBody = (wrapperId: string) => {
    if(!document) return null
    const wrapperElement = document.createElement("div")
    wrapperElement.setAttribute('id', wrapperId)
    document.body.appendChild(wrapperElement)
    return wrapperElement
 }

 function ReactPortal({children, wrapperId}: {children: React.ReactElement; wrapperId: string}) {
    const [wrapperElement, setWrapperElement] = useState<HTMLElement>()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        let element = document.getElementById(wrapperId)
        let systemCreated = false

        if(!element) {
            systemCreated = true
            element = createWrapperAndAppendToBody(wrapperId)
        }
        setWrapperElement(element!)

        return () => {
            if(systemCreated && element?.parentNode) {
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
            }
        }
    },[wrapperId])

    if(!wrapperElement) return null
    return createPortal(children, wrapperElement)

 }

 export default ReactPortal
```

I am pretty sure this is fine.

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import ReactPortal from "./ReactPortal";


interface ConfirmationModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    handleClose: () => void 
    children: React.ReactNode

}

export const ConfirmationModal =({children, isOpen, handleClose}:ConfirmationModalProps) => {
//allows to press Escape Key 
 useEffect(() => {
    const closeOnEscapeKey = (e: KeyboardEvent) =>
        e.key === 'Escape' ? handleClose() : null
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)
        return () => {
            document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscapeKey)
        };
 },[handleClose])

 //stops scrolling fuction when modal is open
 useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    return (): void => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'unset'
    }
 },[isOpen])

 if(!isOpen) return null

 return (
   <ReactPortal wrapperId='react-portal-modal-container'>
    <>
        <div className='fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen z-40 bg-neutral-800 opacity-50' />
        <div className='fixed  rounded flex flex-col box-border min-w-fit overflow-hidden p-5 bg-zinc-800 inset-y-32 inset-x-32'>
            <button className='py-2 px-8 self-end font-bold hover:bg-violet-600 border rounded' 
            onClick={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
                Close
            </button>
        <div className='box-border h-5/6'>{children}</div>
        </div>
    </>
   </ReactPortal>
 )
}
```

This is my reusable Modal component so that I do not have to build a new modal from scratch. The close button within here is no also not working/can't event click on it via a console.log('pressed')

Here is a picture of the modal, but none of the buttons work, however, my Escape key function does work. Any thoughts would be great!
[image]